# Why is SSIS complaining that "There is a partial row at the end of the file"?

Tags: ssis

I'm importing a flat file into a database using a Data Flow Task in SSIS.  The file is very simple: it contains three comma-separated values per row.  Whenever I run this task, however, I receive a warning from the Flat File component:

> Warning: 0x8020200F: There is a partial row at the end of the file.

This warning seems to happen regardless of the size of the file: even with only a handful of rows in the file, visually validated (with extended characters and whatnot visible) I still receive it.  Moreover, it doesn't seem to matter whether I have a blank row at the end of the file or I just end it without a trailing CR+LF.

How can I get rid of this warning so I can run my package with **WarnAsError** enabled?

(BTW, it seems someone else may have had a similar problem in [There is a partial row at the end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530326/there-is-a-partial-row-at-the-end-of-the-file), though it wasn't much of a question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found three things to try if you encounter this problem.  In at least two out of the three cases, SSIS was ignoring rows of my input file with only the above warning to show for it.  Because of that, **I do not recommend ignoring this warning!**

### Step 1: verify that your flat file is valid

This error will appear when you have an invalid input file.  This can be especially hard to detect if your input file has millions of lines, as mine do, but it's vital that you discover file format violations because SSIS will happily give you this warning and continue on its way without importing the offending lines or, in some cases, the lines *after* the offending lines.  The easiest way I found to discover a problem with the source file is to check the number of rows that are being imported successfully.  If it's vastly different than the number you expect in your flat file, something may have gone wrong in the middle somewhere.

### Step 2: try a dummy line at the end (fixed-width only)

If you are using a fixed-width format input file, Microsoft may have a helpful [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937969) for you.  Basically, they suggest that you add a dummy line at the end of the file.

I am not using fixed-width files, so I can't say how useful this technique is.

### Step 3: turn off text qualification for non-text

This is the tricky one, because I believe the *TextQualified* property is **True** by default.  If your input file uses non-text fields (integers, etc.), then you must tell SSIS that it should not expect those columns to be qualified as text.  Essentially, your input file will be invalid in spite of looking perfectly valid.

*TextQualified* is a property of the columns in your Flat File Connection Manager.

[image: Connection Managers]

To change it, open up your connection manager, click "Advanced", and then click on a non-text column.  Make sure the *TextQualified* property is set to **False**.  You will need to do this for all of your non-text columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the byte width of a line in the file is known, you can always double check that the total byte size of the file can be divided by the expected line size to give you a nice round line count number (as opposed to a decimal).

It helps also to know from your source just how many records are expected, but if you don't have this you can at least double check the resultant loaded tables record count against the calculation of line count while loading the file.

I've seen this error often when a source flat text file is missing it's last \r\n at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Running on Windows 64 bit is perfect.  It led to no missing row, but I lost the last row  when running on Windows 2008.

My workaround is
1. open the ssis in BIDs on the Windows 2008. 
2. open the file connection manager make sure Text Qualifier set to 
3. rebuild it

All work fine in both Windows 7 and Windows 2008.